# Update Random Each Repetition of Animate

Tags: random, animation

I found a solution that's not what I wanted but it will suffice
Thanks - Larry

```
col = RandomChoice[{Blue, Red}];
frames = Table[Graphics[{
     col, Disk[{5*t - 5, 5*t - 5}, .5]},
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
   {t, 0, 2, .03}];
ListAnimate[frames, 50]
```

Comment: Easiest fix is to use `col := RandomChoice[{Blue, Red}];`.  The way you have it, `col` is defined once before the `Table`.  With `:=`, it is recomputed each time.  See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html for more info.

Comment: No. That just updates for each frame. I wanted it to update only when the animation starts over.

Comment: I tried that suggestion and it doesn’t work. ??

Comment: I found a solution that' s not quite what I wanted but it will suffice.
Thanks - Larry

 frames = {};
 For[k = 1, k < 5, k++, col2 = RandomChoice[{Blue, Red}];
  frame2 = 
  Table[Graphics[{col2, Disk[{5*t - 5, 5*t - 5}, .5]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {t, 0, 2, .2}];
  frames = Flatten[Append[frames, frame2]];]
 ListAnimate[frames, 5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]

Answer (score 3):

Not continuously random but random for 20 sets.  If a viewer sees the repeating pattern with the 20 sets, they need a life.

```
frames = Table[Graphics[{c, Disk[{5*t - 5, 5*t - 5}, .5]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {t, 0, 2, .03}];
ListAnimate[Flatten[Table[frames /. c -> RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green, Cyan, Orange, Black}], 
  {i, 1, 20}], 1], 100]
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thank you JimB, infinite unnecessary. Much better than mine - Larry

Answer (score 1):

Putting the definition of `col` in a `Module` works:

```
frames := Module[{col},
   col = RandomChoice[{Blue, Red}]; 
   Table[Graphics[{col, Disk[{5*t - 5, 5*t - 5}, .5]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {t, 0, 2, .03}]
];

ListAnimate[frames, 50]
```

Comment: Don’t know why this doesn’t work on my Dell Intel I5, Mathematica 11.2 Home Edition, Win 11. Only updates when it’s re-executed.

Comment: I guess I still didn't get what you're looking for -- this does generate a new color each time `ListAnimate` is run.  Sorry!

Comment: All set now Cris K. I appreciate your help,  it’s my first animated rodeo.